# Must every manifold bundle be a fiber bundle?

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, fiber-bundles

I have been learning differential geometry from [this](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLPH7f_7ZlzxTi6kS4vCmv4ZKm9u8g5yic) lecture series by Frederic Schuller's. [Here](https://youtu.be/uGEV0Wk0eIk?list=PLPH7f_7ZlzxTi6kS4vCmv4ZKm9u8g5yic&t=1385) he defines a bundle (of topological manifolds) as

> A triple, $(E, \pi, M),$ where $E$ and $M$ are topological manifolds and $\pi:E \longrightarrow M$ is a surjective and continuous function.

[Here](https://youtu.be/uGEV0Wk0eIk?list=PLPH7f_7ZlzxTi6kS4vCmv4ZKm9u8g5yic&t=2019) he defines a *fiber* bundle as

> A bundle $(E, \pi, M)$ such that $\forall p \in M: \text{preim}_\pi \big(\{p\}\big) \cong F$ for some manifold $F$.

Using these definitions (which I hope are standard), does there exist some bundle of topological manifolds that is **not** a fiber bundle (i.e., has fibers that are not homeomorphic to each other)?

Sidenote, Schuller provides examples [here](https://youtu.be/uGEV0Wk0eIk?list=PLPH7f_7ZlzxTi6kS4vCmv4ZKm9u8g5yic&t=1893) and [here](https://youtu.be/uGEV0Wk0eIk?list=PLPH7f_7ZlzxTi6kS4vCmv4ZKm9u8g5yic&t=3900) of bundles over a *set* that are not fiber bundles, but the base set is not a manifold in either case, as he clarifies in [this](https://youtu.be/XZcKSoI17r0?list=PLPH7f_7ZlzxTi6kS4vCmv4ZKm9u8g5yic&t=5544) later video.

EDIT: I'll clarify that the $F$ in the definition of fiber bundle is intended to be the same $F$ for each point $p$, i.e., a fiber bundle is a bundle whose fibers are all homeomorphic to each other.

Comment: This is an offensively bad definition, sure to cause confusion. *Most* surjective continuous maps are not fiber bundles. And the definition of fiber bundle is not even correct.

Comment: Does anyone know if these definitions are common among physicists?

Comment: @Mike Miller can you give an example and explain why?

Comment: @WillG Take the projection $[0,1]\to S^1=[0,1]/\sim$, where here $\sim$ identifies $0$ and $1$. Then the fiber above the equivalence class of $0$ has two points in it but the fiber above any other point has only one point

Comment: @liebnewtz I should have mentioned Schuller's definition of manifolds excludes manifolds with boundaries, so $[0,1]$ would not be allowed as the total space $E$ under these definitions.

Comment: @WillG The example has essentially nothing to do with manifolds with boundary. Some other options: collapse an arc in $S^1$ to a point; then you have a continuous map from the circle itself in which all fibers but one are points, and the remaining fiber is an arc. Or consider the exponential map $\Bbb R \to S^1$ restricted to $(-\epsilon, 2\pi+\epsilon)$, which mostly mostly has 1-point preimage but has a few 2-point preimages. You can rig up self-maps of the circle so that some fibers are Cantor sets!

Comment: @leibnewtz: Unfortunately, yes, see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2176044/question-about-the-definition-of-a-fibration

Comment: I suggest, you avoid using either definition that he gives. They are good for the intuition but you cannot prove much with these definitions; the actual definition (that is of a locally trivial fiber bundle or, more generally, a fibration in the sense of Hurewicz or Serre) is much more restrictive. Better, first read the wikipedia article: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fiber_bundle